# VM with multiple StorageProfiles

Tags: c#, sdk, vmware, vcloud-director-rest-api

I'm using the .NET version of the vCloud SDK from VMware. I have a VM with two storages, one of type "x" and the other of type "y".

However, when calling vm.Resource.StorageProfile.name I only get the name of the first disk (x)

```
vCloudClient client = new vCloudClient(url,   com.vmware.vcloud.sdk.constants.Version.V1_5);
client.Login(userName,pass);
Organization organisation = Organization.GetOrganizationByReference(client, client.GetOrgRefsByName()[orgName]);
Vdc vdc = Vdc.GetVdcByReference(client,organisation.GetVdcRefByName(vdcName));
ReferenceType vappref = vdc.GetVappRefByName("myVappName");
Vapp vapp = Vapp.GetVappByReference(client,vappref);
List<VM> vms = vapp.GetChildrenVms();
foreach(VM vm in vms)
{
   //VM I'm having trouble with
   string storageprofile = vm.Resource.StorageProfile.name //returns value: x
}
```

Is there any other way to get both the "x" and "y" storages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey try parsing via the vdc storage profile instead

heres the link type for it:

"https://vcloud-example/api/query?type=orgVdcStorageProfile"

If that is not what you need you need to search for the Storage Profile list itself, where it gives href or a link type for EACH storage policy with their name and href type link for that specific storage policy

most probably vm.GetDisks gives you the storage policy "link" (im not sure, but i think it should, I dont use C#, but python and powershell)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have tried both of your suggestions, the first one gives me a "This operation is denied." and the second a "ACCESS_TO_RESOURCE_IS_FORBIDDEN - DISALLOWED_OPERATIONS". I assume this has to do with permissions but the login information I'm using has to be correct.

Comment: I have managed to find the storageprofiles by using this query: "https://vcloud-example/api/query?type=orgVdcStorageProfile". Thank you very much! I will edit your answer to this and mark it as the answer if that's alright.

Comment: lol sure.. looks like you dont have admin priveleges huh... anyway just remember that if the storage profiles are more than say 30 it wont list all of them, you might have to change the pagesize in the query

Answer (score 0):

vm.GetDisks should return all disks.

Comment: True however, the virtual disks do not contain the names of the storageprofiles and that's what I need.